# Create shipment error not found carrier

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-4

When I tried to create Shipment for an order in Dear System, I am having error saying  `[{"ErrorCode":404,"Exception":"Specified Carrier Express Courier International' not found."}]` and only those orders with same carrier have a problem the rest of the orders were successfully created a shipment/SaleShip. 
I referred to this docs: http://support.dearsystems.com/support/solutions/articles/1000180066-saleship

Can someone give me idea what causes this error and the possible solution for this? Thank you so much.

Comment: its specific to dear system, better you contact their support

Comment: Their support are the best people to help you.